# What is the "i" of the Sedgewick's Gap Sequence formula?

Tags: c++, sorting, shellsort

The *Sedgewick's Gap Sequence* can be calculated with 4*9^i-9*2^i+1 and 4^i-3*2^i+1. What is the value of "i"?

Comment: You can't really be serious. `i` is clearly a variable, and is whatever value is assigned to it. "I want to add two to `i`? What value is it before and after `i = i + 2;`?"

Comment: Do you have some code issues, or another problem you are trying to solve here?  As presented I think its a little off topic.

Comment: so, I should put this formula in a for loop and increment the value of i?

Comment: I believe Ken has illustrated why your question is meaningless, And I am suggesting that you have either not clearly presented what you are really after, or you are playing games.

Comment: Im not playing any game, I know it is a variable, but I dont know what valuse should I put

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform a shellsort, you compute the gap sequence, sometimes called the increment sequence, using i starting at 1 and incrementing it until it's large enough to sensibly start sorting (Sedgewick suggests that when you get the largest gap sequence less than `N/3`).

Then you shellsort starting with the largest gap down to 1.

Note: the gap sequence equations you posted don't seem to agree with what's on [Wikipedia's shellsort page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort#Gap_sequences) and don't seem to work. You might want to verify the equations you want to use.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. Is nice to see that there is still people that want to help!

Comment: @user2175394: in fairness to the people complaining about the question, there wasn't even a mention of shellsort, so the context of gap sequences might not be obvious.  I wouldn't have known what you were asking about except that you mentioned Sedgewick.